# "Instantiating" custom types that inherit from GameObject

Tags: inheritance, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to "Instantiate" a custom type to the scene. I made it inherit from GameObject by doing so:

```
Block.prototype = new GameObject();
```

So,

-will this work, will it inherit from GameObject?

-And how can I "Instantiate" it?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit **GameObject**.

You need to inherit [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

After you inherit from `MonoBehaviour` you attach a Component to a GameObject, you can create this from the Unity menu `GameObject->Create Empty` and then drag and drop it on the Project view. This wil create a `Prefab` that you can `Instantiate`.

To Instantiate a GameObject you need to call

```
Resources.Load("path_to_prefab")
```

The prefab needs to be under a folder called `Resources`. More on `Resources.Load` [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

Answer (score 0):

if its type is `gameobject` you can make a `prefab` out of it and then `instantiate` it if it isnt a `gameobject` then you can attach it to a `gameObject` make a `prefab` then instantiate the `gameobject`
assign  the `prefab` in inspector then use `Instantiate`

```
public GameObject prefab;
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
```